# Angular DOMSanitizationService is undefined

Tags: angular

In my component, I am trying to do two way binding for a property. Here is my component code:

```
  constructor(public _DomSanitizationService: DomSanitizer ) {}

  ngOnInit(){
    this.hello();
    this.intervalId = setInterval(this.hello, 1000);
  }

  hello(){
    this.socket.on('image_data', (data: any) => {
      this.image = this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:image/png;base64, " + data;
    });
  }
```

There is no error when ngOnInit executes but when the `setInterval` executes the `this._domSanitizationService` is undefined. I don't know what is causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to reassign the value of **this** inorder to get scope inside the function . Try a solution like this :

```
  hello(){
    var _this = this;
    this.socket.on('image_data', (data: any) => {
      _this.image = _this._DomSanitizationService.bypassSecurityTrustUrl("data:image/png;base64, " + data;
    });
  }
```